# Heroku python install pre-requirements before main requirements

Tags: python, git, heroku, cython, requirements.txt

I am trying to push a python flask app to heroku. I have a requirements.txt file, but I am unable to figure out how do I install the pre-requisites that are needed to install one of the dependencies in the requirements.txt file. I have a github repo in my requirements.txt file as a dependency but that requires `Cython` and `numpy` to install. On adding `Cython` and `numpy` to my requirements.txt file, it shows an error even when `Cython` and `numpy` are there before the github repo in the requirements.txt file.

Error log

```
      File "/Users/sayam/Desktop/ti-heroku/venv3/src/detectron/setup.py", line 12, in <module>
        from Cython.Build import cythonize
    ImportError: No module named Cython.Build
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

requirements.txt

```
Cython==0.29.14
numpy==1.16.5
-e git+https://github.com/facebookresearch/densepose@35e69d110b432704c2183cd6aea531f4f695edbe#egg=Detectron
```

Note that Cython and numpy are mentioned before in the requirements.txt file still it gives an error.

The github repo which I'm referring here has the following in its setup.py file.

```
# Copyright (c) Facebook, Inc. and its affiliates.
# All rights reserved.
#
# This source code is licensed under the license found in the
# LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree.
##############################################################################

from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

from Cython.Build import cythonize
from setuptools import Extension
from setuptools import setup

import numpy as np

_NP_INCLUDE_DIRS = np.get_include()


# Extension modules
ext_modules = [
    Extension(
        name='detectron.utils.cython_bbox',
        sources=[
            'detectron/utils/cython_bbox.pyx'
        ],
        extra_compile_args=[
            '-Wno-cpp'
        ],
        include_dirs=[
            _NP_INCLUDE_DIRS
        ]
    ),
    Extension(
        name='detectron.utils.cython_nms',
        sources=[
            'detectron/utils/cython_nms.pyx'
        ],
        extra_compile_args=[
            '-Wno-cpp'
        ],
        include_dirs=[
            _NP_INCLUDE_DIRS
        ]
    )
]

setup(
    name='Detectron',
    packages=['detectron'],
    ext_modules=cythonize(ext_modules)
)
```

Also since it's Heroku, I can't manually do `pip install Cython` and `pip install numpy` before running requirements.txt file.

Please suggest a solution to this problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cython error when pushing git on heroku master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46611178/cython-error-when-pushing-git-on-heroku-master)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cython+heroku

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51674612/7976758

Comment: That first question you link to is pretty bad - a tiny description and some bad photographs of a screen. I suspect it would be better to get a decent answer on this (or another duplicate if possible) and then closing the other, hopefully never to be seen again. Or edit the question into something worthwhile.

Comment: @phd I have already seen that and that post doesn't describe the problem precisely and the solution mentioned isn't complete. I have provided all the information available and I'd like a more descriptive reply than the one ones on the post you're referring to, to get a better understanding of the problem.